# Django: Cannot create model with a Field that maps to different models

Tags: django, django-models, database-design

In my app, I have a model called `Supplier` and multiple models like `Part`, `Fuel`, `Ink`, etc., which are all a some form of *resource* that a supplier might supply.

I want to be able to fetch all resources for a given supplier, and figured I would implement this efficiently by making a `SupplierResource` model with two fields: `supplier` and `resource` (`resource` be a foreign key to an object in either one of the "resource" tables).

But this, does not seem to work, because I can't create a foreign key that maps to different models.

Here are example models:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    minimum_order_quantity = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(...)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(...)
    # ...


class Resource(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        related_name="supplier_part",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Part(Resource):
    some_attr = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class Fuel(Resource):
    some_other_attr = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I could iterate through all child models of `Resource` to collect resources for a given supplier but that would be very slow.

I would prefer not using polymorphism to avoid unnecessary complexity (unless it turns out this is strictly necessary).

Comment: You don't have to iterate through all child of `Resource`. You can just iterate all `Resource` and see if they are `Part` or `Fuel` types. Anyway [this](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/) is a nice read before you go on the path of generic foreign keys

Comment: May I ask what is the reason behind that you absolutely need the resources each as a individual model. I think that structure is not helpfull at the basis and the root of the problem. What happens with a new resource? Each time you will have to modify the code and add a new model? If I understand the background maybe it is easier to support you with a really simple solution.

Comment: Resources are very different from each other and have many different attributes. Therefore, they have to be different. Resources have to b considered as products. Do you have a better solution / model structure.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider to use [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic).

If you do this, just let Resource inherit from PolymorphicModel like this:

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class Supplier(models.Model):
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    minimum_order_quantity = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


class Resource(PolymorphicModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class Part(Resource):
    some_attr = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class Fuel(Resource):
    some_other_attr = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

And then you can create the SupplierResource model like the following:

```
class SupplierResource(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or, a many to many relations between Supplier and Resource:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    minimum_order_quantity = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    resources = models.ManyToManyField(Resource, related_name="suppliers")
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by C14L you can use a GenericForeignKey to create a relationship with another model. However GenericForeignKeys come with their own issues. They don't create reverse relationships. So you wouldn't be able to do, for example, `[sr.supplier for sr in Part.supplier_resources]`, however it would allow you to get rid of your `Resource` parent model. What you've got with the Resource parent model is the right idea I believe. I would suggest in the
resource model, you add a field a field called `child_model_name`

```py
class Resource(models.Model):
    child_model_name = models.TextField()
    some_attr = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

where `child_model_name = 'part'` etc..

Then in your SupplierResource Model you have

```py
class SupplierResource(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, ..., related_name="supplier_resources")
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, ..., related_name="supplier_resources")
```

Here what django is doing for you is creating a table called `Resource` that contains all the fields for a Resource. It also creates a table for you called Part with fields specific to a part that has a OneToOne relationship to Resource.

Now can you do this:

`parts = Part.objects.filter(supplier_rescources__supplier=supplier)`

Or to get different types of resource in one list (Part, fuel etc).

```py
resources = Resource.objects.filter(supplier_resources__supplier=supplier)

[getattr(resource, resource.child_model_name) for resource in resources]
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is my resource models is Abstract. I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Generic Foreign Keys? They use `content_type` and `object_id` to map the same field to different models:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations